# DataFrame.resample() is duplicating columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, `self.data`, which has some columns that I am interested in and some columns that I can drop.

When I want to select a column from the DataFrame, I call `self.data[column]`, and I return a Series.

I assemble a list of columns `self.useful_columns`, a snapshot of which is shown below:

`useful_columns = ['P(M): ~RackA\\Cnd\\Ctrl (kPa)', 'P(C): ~RackA\\Cnd\\CtrlStPt (kPa)', ...]`

I then resample the DataFrame, passing in the list of useful columns, expecting to filter out the columns that I do not care about and resample the DataFrame to the time interval that I want.

`self.data = self.data[self.useful_columns].resample(interval).mean()`

Once I carry out the resample, when I select the same column `self.data[column]`, I return a DataFrame, not a Series.

Both of the columns that now have the same name in the new DataFrame have the same data.

Somewhat confusingly, if I select a different column from the DataFrame (which also exists in the `useful_columns` list), I return a Series both times. The datatypes of both this appropriately behaving column and the column that gets duplicated are `float64`.

Any thoughts as to what is causing the duplication of columns?

Comment: Upon further debugging, looks like the problem occurs when I select the columns from the original DataFrame. `self.data = self.data[self.useful_columns]` causes the selection of the column to return a Series

Comment: Ah, looks like there were some duplicate names in the list of useful columns